# How can I call MBean operation using jboss-cli.sh?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jmx

Like in the title, how can I call operation using jboss-cli.sh?

I'm already tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/client/jboss-cli.sh --connect --server=127.0.0.1:8080 invoke "package.foo:bar=MBeanName" operation_name
```

Comment: I don't think `jboss-cli` supports a raw interface to JMX. That `invoke` syntax comes from the old `twiddle` utility, I think. Is there something you need from Wildfly via JMX that cannot be obtained using the regular management model?

Comment: What do you mean in 'regular management model'? I want to invoke some method on wildfly stopping, but from stopping script

Comment: What I meant is that `jboss-cli` has it's own way of representing the elements of configuration. It's kind-of tree-like as JMX is, but it's not the same structure as is exposed in JMX. I'm told that all aspects of server operation are exposed by `jboss-cli`, but not in the same way JMX does. There's supposed to be no need to expose JMX directly in the CLI tool. Or so the maintainers say, anyway.